# In MVC3 where does the Add View dialog get its model classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Stumbled up one curiosity that i researched upon but found no exact answer whatsoever. I was adding a view to my mvc project when i noticed that when mentioning the model for the view lots of classes appear to wich i have no reference in a direct way. For example i can see in the add view dialog all the ClosedXml classes for excel but that dll is referenced in my Bussines Logic project, not in the web project for sure. So 1. why does it appear in the models dropdown in the add view dialog? 2.Should this list not be composed only of classes from the models folder? Sorry if this is a silly question but nevertheless no one could give me a straight answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All public classes that are part of the current solution appear in this list, not only those that are declared in a Model folder in the current assembly. Even classes in referenced assemblies will appear. Some classes will be filtered out though:

- Types ending in `Controller` (to avoid seeing your controllers in the list)
- Types declared in the `System` or `Microsoft` namespace

Comment: Thank you, the documentation is theoretically zero on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Besides of the answer of @DarinDimitrov

> For example i can see in the add view dialog all the ClosedXml classes for excel but that dll is referenced in my Bussines Logic project

It seems Visual Studio iterates over all your references, so I assume you do have a reference to your business component in your MVC project

Now the reason?, well that's because you could practically use any `public` entity as your model

> 2.Should this list not be composed only of classes from the models folder?

**NO**

A model in MVC is a simple class to **represent your view**, please do not get confused about your current Domain Model. They used the same term but a model in MVC is just that, a simple class to **represent your view and NOTHING MORE**

With that in mind, you could use any public class as your model.

I think that's the reason behind although, I rarely use that option in Visual Studio because often it takes too much time to display the content of the list, so I prefer to set the model manually